# Deriviation behind trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In an example of a trigonometry book I'm reading, I see the following operations performed on this equation $r = (r+3)\cos2.23^\circ$:

$$
\\\
\\\
r = 3\cos2.23^\circ + r \cos2.23^\circ 
\\\
\\\
r - r \cos2.23 = 3\cos2.23^\circ
\\\
\\\
r = \left(\frac{3\cos2.23^\circ}{1 - \cos2.23^\circ} \right)
\\\
\\\
$$

Where $r$ is the radius of a circle. The problem is that I can't understand how the second line in the above operations goes to the third. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Just factor "r" in the left hand side of second line and then divide to get the third line.

Comment: Derp, yeah as soon as I saw the answer I did a mental facepalm for myself lol. This is the result of not taking a math class for six months :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second line you have,

$$r-r\cos(2.23)=3\cos(2.23) $$

Factor out an r from the left hand side,

$$r(1-\cos(2.23))=3\cos(2.23) $$

Then divide both sides by $(1-\cos(2.23))$  Hope that helps!

Comment: It does! Thank you very much; I'll accept your answer when the wait limit is over.

Comment: Excellent!  Cheers.